# Record / playback keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, automator

There are 3rd party apps but I'm not interested in those.  I'm a web developer and during testing I find myself entering login credentials over and over again.  If I could quickly "play" these keystorkes it would help my sanity.  I'm assuming Automator can do this?  I've never used Automater so a complete answer for that would be appreciated.  However I would prefer something even more native if it's possible.

Comment: So basically you want to fill a login form with a username and a password automatically? Is it always the same username and password?

Comment: Yes. I realize I could just put that into the form's source ... or even have a TestingSessionProvider for my ISession object. But it would just be easier to play keystrokes if it's already built into the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that there are lots of good third party apps for automatically logging in to web forms. I highly recommend using one of those.

To answer your question: Yes, you can do this with a combination of Automator and AppleScript. Here's how.

Open Automator. Go to File-> New. Select `Service`.
Type `applescript` into the search bar near the top left.
Drag the `Run AppleScript` item to the area on the right.
Replace the purple code that starts in the box with this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "username"
    keystroke tab
    keystroke "password"
end tell
```

Now replace the `username` text with your username, and replace the `password` text with your password.
This will have the computer type your username, hit tab, and type your password.
Now, at the top of the Automator window, set `Service receives` to `no input` and `in` to the app you need this to happen in.
Automator shoud now look like this:
[image]

Save this and give it a name. Now, go to the app you selected at the top right and put your cursor in the username field.

Go to the app's menu (next to the Apple menu) and choose Services-> {*what you named your Automator app*}.

It should run the Automator workflow and 'play back' the keystrokes.

Again, this is the hard, insecure way. I highly recommend apps like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/products/1Password) and [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/).

Comment: I realize it's insecure but this will always be a test account on a dev machine running a local instance of the site. This is perfect and also gets my toes wet with Animator and AppleScript. Thank you for the thorough answer and I will try it tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to input a username and a password automatically, simply go to `Safari > Preferences > Autofill` and select "User Names and Passwords". In theory that should ask you upon submiting the form if you want Safari to remember it, and if you select yes, it will store it in your Keychain.

Next time you visit the website you will just have to type the first character and Safari will automatically fill in the rest for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's way too easy. I'm a programmer. I need to solve it with a hammer!

Comment: hahaha agree. good luck then! :)